# Вывод постов из кастомного типа записей

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Вот так объявляю кастомный тип записи

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init(){
    register_post_type('flats', array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'               => 'Недвижимость',
            'singular_name'      => 'Недвижимость',
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить новую недвижимость',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавить новую недвижимость',
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактировать недвижимость',
            'new_item'           => 'Новая недвижимость',
            'view_item'          => 'Посмотреть недвижимость',
            'search_items'       => 'Найти недвижимость',
            'not_found'          => 'Ничего не найдено',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине нет недвижимости',
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'Недвижимость'

          ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array('title','excerpt')
    ) );
}
```

Вот так пытаюсь вывести посты

```
       <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post);
            the_title();
            echo get_field('object_name');
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        ?>
```

Но посты не выводятся. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо указать тип записей, иначе по умолчанию выборка делается из стандартного типа `post`.

```
<?php
global $post;

$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'flats',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'offset'         => 1,
    'category'       => 1,
];

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
    echo get_field( 'object_name' );
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так выводится

```
<?php
    global $post;
    
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'flats',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    ];
    
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        the_title();
        echo get_field( 'object_name' );
    }
    
    wp_reset_postdata();
```